# How many constraints can be given to a column of a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Can anyone explain me how many constraints at most can be set on any given column of a table in SQL Server.

Comment: are you asking because you have specific business need with lots of constraints in mind, or are you asking for academic reasons>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constraints:

- Primary key
- NULL/NOT NULL
- DEFAULT
- UNIQUE (likely conflict with DEFAULT)
- Foreign Key (unlimited that I'm aware of, not that you want more than one typically)
- CHECK (also unlimited to my knowledge, but extremely odd to see more than one)

Comment: I forgot CHECK... and NULL/NOT NULL constraints

Comment: I'd be concerned that there was a design problem if you you needed more than one of any of those and agree Unique likely to conflict with default.

Comment: @HLGEM: Agreed.  And Unique on a primary key could be redundant, with implications for composites...

Answer (score 5):

"It depends"

- Primary key  (maximum one if clustered, or part of max nonclustered indexes = 999 on SQL Server 2008)
- DEFAULT (maximum one per column)
- NULL/NOT NULL (one or the other per column). Yes, this is a constraint
- CHECK (column or table level: lots)
- UNIQUE (part of max nonclustered indexes = 999 on SQL Server 2008, 1 if clustered)
- FOREIGN KEY (max 253)

Notes:

- things like one IDENTITY or timestamp/rowversion or ROWGUIDCOL per table
- you have a max of 1024 columns per standard table which obvious limits number of defaults
- some will be mutually exclusive

Some taken from here: [Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Don't think there is a practical limit, I just created a table with more than 9k constraints:

```
create table #TheresNoLimit (
    id int,
    constraint constr1 check (id = 1),
    constraint constr2 check (id = 1),
    constraint constr3 check (id = 1),
    ...
    constraint constr9985 check (id = 1)
)
```