# SQL - Max no of UNIQUE Constraint per table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How many UNIQUE Constraint can be created per table? Is there any limitations?

Comment: In general, this is the sort of question that should make you pause and consider whether you're taking the right approach/using the right tools to solve your problem.

Comment: Not necessarily. For example, when using a Memory Optimized Table you are severely limited in the number of indexes.

Comment: For SQL Server 2005:
1 Clustered Index + 249 Nonclustered Index = 250 Index
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432(SQL.90).aspx

For SQL Server 2008:
1 Clustered Index + 999 Nonclustered Index = 1000 Index
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx

Reference : Pinal Dave - blog.sqlauthority.com
 https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/06/29/sql-server-maximum-number-of-index-per-table/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx), maximum number of nonclustered indexes per table (which is what unique constrains use under the hood) is limited to 999.

Answer (score 2):

From [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390717/how-many-constraints-can-be-given-to-a-column-of-a-table-in-sql-server) :

> "It depends"
>
> - Primary key  (maximum one if clustered, or part of max nonclustered indexes = 999 on SQL Server 2008)
> - DEFAULT (maximum one per column)
> - NULL/NOT NULL (one or the other per column). Yes, this is a constraint
> - CHECK (column or table level: lots)
> - **UNIQUE (part of max nonclustered indexes = 999 on SQL Server 2008, 1 if clustered)**
> - FOREIGN KEY (max 253)
>
> Notes:
>
> - things like one IDENTITY or timestamp/rowversion or ROWGUIDCOL per table
> - you have a max of 1024 columns per standard table which obvious limits number of defaults
> - some will be mutually exclusive
>
> Some taken from here: [Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL
>   Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you create a unique constraint then by default a non-clustered Index has been created. You can create a maximum of 999 (Non-Clustered Indexes) per table as per limitations.

```
You can create 999 Unique constraints per table.
```

This is applicable from SQL Server 2008R2 to SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can find all limitations about [**Sql Server environment**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)

Because you can'ìt specify Sql Server version, I posted the last (Sql Server 2016) but in that page you can switch to other versions.

So there's no a limitation about number of constraints. You have only this:

> Database objects include objects such as tables, views, stored
>   procedures, user-defined functions, triggers, rules, defaults, and
>   constraints. The sum of the number of all objects in a database cannot
>   exceed 2,147,483,647.

Answer (score 0):

> **Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server** [here an article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)

**Bytes per index key :**

> The maximum number of bytes in a clustered index key cannot exceed 900
>   in SQL Server. For a nonclustered index key, the maximum is 1700
>   bytes.
>
> You can define a key using variable-length columns whose maximum sizes
>   add up to more than the limit. However, the combined sizes of the data
>   in those columns can never exceed the limit.
>
> In a nonclustered index, you can include extra non-key columns, and
>   they do not count against the size limit of the key. The non-key
>   columns might help some queries perform better.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the table type.

If using a Memory Optimized Table in SQL Server 2014, you can only have one unique index, which is your primary key. (And 8 non-unique secondary indexes.)

If using a Clustered Columnstore in SQL Server 2014, you officially can't have any unique indexes (again, other than the primary key). However, you can technically get one by creating a view on the table, then creating a unique index on that view.